# FVWM: Make xterm stay on top, conditionally

Tags: x11, xterm, window-management, fvwm

Algorithm: *If there is no window currently on top, then make the next new
xterm stay on top (layer 6).*

I got that to work:

```
Module FvwmEvent

AddToFunc MyUpdate
+ I WindowStyle StaysOnTop

AddToFunc MyUpdateIfXterm
+ I Current ("XTerm") MyUpdate

AddToFunc MyUpdateIfLayer6Empty
+ I None (Layer 6) MyUpdateIfXterm

*FvwmEvent: Cmd
*FvwmEvent: add_window MyUpdateIfLayer6Empty

Style * ClickToFocus
```

Now, I want that xterm on top also to be without title, and so I change the
fourth line to:

```
+ I WindowStyle StaysOnTop, NoTitle
```

This, however, stops xterm from going to top. It looks like `StaysOnTop`
stopped working.

*Did I run into a bug? If so, is there a workaround?*

Version:

```
$ fvwm --version
fvwm 2.6.5 compiled on May 15 2014 at 22:08:55
with support for: ReadLine, Stroke, XPM, PNG, SVG, Shape, XShm, SM, Bidi text, Xinerama, XRender, XCursor, XFT, NLS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting `UpdateStyles` right after moving the window to top does the trick:

```
AddToFunc MyUpdate
+ I WindowStyle StaysOnTop
+ I UpdateStyles
+ I WindowStyle NoTitle
```

From documentation:

> ### Delayed Execution of Commands
>
> Note: There are many commands that affect look and feel of specific, some or
>   all windows, like *Style, Mouse, Colorset, TitleStyle* and many others. For
>   performance reasons such changes are not applied immediately but only when
>   fvwm is idle, i.e. no user interaction or module input is pending.
>   Specifically, new *Style* options that are set in a function are not applied
>   until after the function has completed. This can sometimes lead to unwanted
>   effects.
>
> To force that all pending changes are applied immediately, use the
>   *UpdateStyles, Refresh* or *RefreshWindow* commands.